# How accurate is setTimeout/setInterval in Node.js and the browser?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm setting a timer in Node.js that waits for 3 hours to emit an event, once that time is reached it emits the event to all browsers that are listening.

The browsers gathers the information that such event before it happens and then calculates the time remaining ticking a countdown every 1 second, and expecting that when the clock reaches 0 the event will be triggered.

So one is using `setTimeout` (Node.js) and the other is using `setInterval` (browser) counting per second (countdown).

can I be sure that?

- By the time the countdown reaches 0, the event will be triggered with an error range of around 1 to 2 seconds. (browser).
- That the Node.js `setTimeout` is accurate enough to be called with a less than 1 second error range.

I've read about timers being 500ms to even 1000ms innacurate, which is fine for my needs, but I have never heard of them being used for this much time as I want to do.

Are they accurate enough or should I use a different solution? especially in the Node.js side which has to be the most accurate of them all.

- Alternatives are to make a interval in Node.js that runs around 4 times per second, calculates the Date milliseconds, and checks if there are events that it needs to call from a list of events.
- In the browser is to set the interval so that it calculates the date ms with every callback to try to keep the time synchronized.

Answer (score 4):

The accuracy of the timer will be dependent upon how "busy" the event loop is at the time of the timeout.

It should be good enough if you wanted something like:

```
setTimeout(done, THREE_HOURS_IN_MS);
```

If your event loop is blocking for any length of time you have other problems.

But if you are sampling four times a second as part of the countdown, then I would expect a large inaccuracy to accrue.

So you may need to keep the two activities (sampling and countdown) separate, or maintain the elapsed time manually.

Note that when your web app does not have focus, the accuracy of timers degrades.